# How to allocate each word to multiple dates in SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a new field which has all date range for every letter in the column

Field 1 contains : A,B

Example each word will be associated with all dates.

```
New Field        Date
A               01/01/2019
A               02/01/2019
A               03/01/2019
etc

SELECT day
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2017-01-01'), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS day
```

This generates the dates I need to combine with A and B

So basically when I combine I should have 2248 rows. 1124 rows for A with different dates and 1124 rows for B with different dates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, letter, day
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(list)) letter, 
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) day
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data based on example from your question, as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'A,B' list UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'C,D,E'
)
SELECT id, letter, day
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(list)) letter, 
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) day
-- ORDER BY day, id, letter
```

with result like below

```
Row id  letter  day  
1   1   A       2020-01-01   
2   1   B       2020-01-01   
3   2   C       2020-01-01   
4   2   D       2020-01-01   
5   2   E       2020-01-01   
6   1   A       2020-01-02   
7   1   B       2020-01-02   
8   2   C       2020-01-02   
. . . 
143 2   C       2020-01-29   
144 2   D       2020-01-29   
145 2   E       2020-01-29
```